# Text indent/white space before select option

Tags: css

[On this page](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/events/index.html), there's a text indent/white space before the select option, but the input has none.

Not sure where it's coming from as the CSS is the same for select, option and input.
The CSS is:

```
input, select {
margin: 0px;
height: 38px;
border: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

select {
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 0.01px;
text-overflow: '';
appearance: none;
}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Which select option? I see more than one... Please be more specific.

Comment: `#search-bar input,#search-bar select {}` has `padding: 0 0 0 15px` which is adding left padding to the `<input>` and `<select>`

Comment: There's no text-indent in any of the elements, they're using padding.

Comment: @88mpg yeah, but is that what the OP means? Cause then he'd see it in the input too. @uname12 `0 0 0 15px` = left 15px;

Comment: Ah, maybe not. In that case, the elements are using IDs to determine the space on the left side (what @andyb said).